# Is it possible to update an F# entity in RavenDB without abandoning immutability?

Tags: f#, ravendb, immutability

I have become a great fan of the powerful type system in F# and how it allows you to create some very tight restraints on your domain models (for those interested, see [this](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/designing-with-types.html)). I have also become a great fan of RavenDB and how it makes database work very simple in most of the cases I run into. However, there seems to be issues getting the two to play nicely together - at least if you insist on immutable types.

As long as you don't ever have to update your entities, all you need to do is make the `id` property mutable. While I'm certainly not happy that this is necessary, I can live with it. However, it seems that change tracking is handled in such a way that you must mutate the original object retrieved from the database and it is not possible to attach a new object to the database to represent an updated version of an existing entity. It does seem to be possible to do what I want using the patching API, but the [documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/partial-document-updates) clearly warns against this type of general usage.

Am I missing a part of the RavenDB API that will let me do this without too much fuss or must I abandon the idea of immutable domain models (or perhaps make a feature request for it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with immutable in that scenario is that you *are* actually dealing with mutable data.
The document is being mutated. The fact that you don't mutate it in user space is of little matter here.
What you *can* do is wrap calls to `Advanced.Evict` & `Store` in a `StoreUpdated` or something like that extension method. But I would call into question the usage of immutable data to represent mutable state.

Comment: I certainly get your point, but there are some reasons why I don't agree in practice. For one, when using F# record types, having to add 'mutable' before every field can add a lot of noise to an otherwise very succinct model definition. Other than that, I like to think of the domain models as immutable objects when passing them around since it does not make sense for abitrary components to be able to change them. The change happens as a part of very explicit business logic and it forces you to think about persistence directly when updating the models.

Comment: But this is definitely a view driven by the F# mentality. I would have no issues with mutability in this case if it had been a C# project.